# Brute force search for pdf password in python

Tags: python, performance, security, pdf

I forgot the password to my pdf. I remembered a few characters, so I made a simple password-cracker program in Python. Is the document lost now given the number of combinations? Out of curiosity, how could I speed up this program as much as possible?

```
from pikepdf import open
from itertools import  product
from math import factorial

c = '12A3ca9€'
c = sorted(set(c))
length = len(c)
total = ( (1-(length**(length+1)))/(1-length) ) - 1

s = 0
for s2 in range(length):
    s2 += 1
    m = product(c, repeat=s2)
    for i in m:
        try:
            with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Document.pdf", password=''.join(i)) as pdf:
                print(len(pdf.pages))
            print(''.join(i))
            exit(0)
        except:
            pass
        s+=1
        print(100*s/total)
```

Comment: Welcome! Not worth an answer yet but in case I do not find time for a review tomorrow, my main comment is that I find it surprising that the search is limited to passwords of maximal length `len(c)` which seems pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Because I tried to make it more tractable, but even then I think it's unlikely to reach a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will never actually test any password, since `password` is not a valid argument for `open()`. Thusly every call to it, will throw a `TypeError`, which is swallowed by your bare `except` clause. Read up on proper PDF libraries that support decryption by password and don't ever use bare except statements.

Comment: No, you are wrong. I get an error "pdf = Pdf._open(
pikepdf._qpdf.PasswordError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Document.pdf: invalid password". I also tried locking a new pdf file. I used the same program to unlock it. I got no exception, I could open the new pdf from my code perfectly. ```password``` is a valid argument. Notice the import statement at the begining, We are not talking about the same ```open()```. Anyways maybe its bad practice to import functions with the same name as built-ins?

Comment: Oh! actually 1 line of code is missing! My bad, I didnt write ```from pikepdf import open``` but it's in my code. Apologies.

Comment: Please don't change your code, once an answer has been posted. See #5: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I didnt change the code, If you see the edits, the line was there from the begining

Comment: I think that says something about using names that are the same as built-in functions.  Perhaps `from pikepdf import open as pdf_open` would have saved the code from silently changing meaning?

Comment: Yes, probably, but my question was more about performance, not readability. But I haven't seen any answer that shows how to significantly improve the speed of the program, yet. I was aware that the print slows it down, but I feel not knowing how many combinations are left is too annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it in C.








On a serious note, performance of your algorithm can be increased but not by a lot, since the bottleneck is definitely trying to open the file over and over.
*[Edit: this is wrong in a weird way; please refer to @RichardNeumann's answer!]*

Remove increments and printing of `s`: it runs on each iteration and doesn't contribute to anything.

You do `s2 += 1` even though `s2` is already being increased by the `for` loop. This is very misleading.
*[Edited. Thanks to @SylvainD!]*

If you think that every symbol appears only once, you can reduce the number of possibilities significantly.

If this doesn't work, I've read that [this tool](https://www.iseepassword.com/pdf-password-recovery.html) has a speed of 100K attempts per second at cracking PDF passwords.

P.S. Please name your variables according to what they actually represent, even thought it's just a small script. I had a hard time reading this.

Comment: Hello, regarding the `s2 += 1`, it is very misleading but no wrong as such. The s2 value would actually go through all values. I'd suggest trying `for i in range(4): i+=1 print(i)`. Your comment assumes that the behavior is the one from a standard C loop but it doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: There's no bottleneck on opening the files since the call to open will immediately fail with a TypeError due to the unsupported kwarg password. So the code fails lightning fast. :D

Comment: @RichardNeumann wow, I just assumed it has that parameter.

Comment: @SylvainD ooh that's right, since it uses local copies of i.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Yes, one line of code wasn't present in the code view, I changed it. There was an import statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Review of the Python code**

Various details about the Python code itself

You code looks good and uses properly various nice features of Python: data types like set and modules like itertools.

- The `m` variable is not that useful
- The auto-increment of `s2` is slightly misleading. Here are a 2 alternatives: directly use `s2+1` to get `product(c, repeat=s2+1)` or get `s2` by iterating over a different range: `for s2 in range(1, length+1)`
- Most variables name convey no actual meaning: `c` is a list (maybe `lst` or `chars`), `s` is a counter (maybe `c` or `nb`), `s2` is a length...
- The way `total` is computed probably deserves some explanation
- `math.factorial` is not used anymore
- `''.join(i)` could be computed just once, before the `try`
- `r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Document.pdf"` could probably be in a constant
- Bare `except` are usually frowned upon as they usually catch more than expected and also provide no meaning about what is being caught to the reader. See [What is wrong with using a bare `except`?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54948548) for more details.

**Comments about the behavior of the program**

If I wanted to use such a tool, here are a few aspects of its behavior that I would most probably change.

- Calling `print` at each iteration will take some time and not give much information to the user. An alternative could be to print `s2` instead: "About to try passwords of lengths X - Y combinations to be tested"
- Stopping at strings of length `sorted(set(c))` seems pretty arbitrary. My suggestion would be to keep going with `itertools.count` instead of `range`.